# Bulk Import task with text qualifier

Tags: ssis

SSIS Bulk Import data transformation Row/Column delimiter definition. Trying to import from a csv file to sql table. After doing the import data/values come as follows

```
Col1 col2 col3  
"XXX" "BBN" "BBB"  
"XXX" "BBN" "BBB"  
"XXX" "BBN" "BBB"
```

data/values are wrapped around double quotes. 
How can i fix this.

Connection manager for csv file has text qualifer: " , 
header row delimiter has {CR}{LR} 
unforunately bulk import doesn't have text qualifier

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you mean that your SSIS package imports the text qualifier from the csv file, but shouldn't?

Comment: 1. I need to import data from CSV file to sql table using SSIS 2. So I use Bulk insert task to import data to sql(cant use flat file source, it takes long time). makes sense??? 3. Now everything works fine, data is in sql table but data is wrapped with double quotes.. consider this as tableA with columns Col1 col2 col3 "XXX" "BBN" "BBB" "XXX" "BBN" "BBB" "XXX" "BBN" "BBB" So i don't need double quotes around data.does my question makes sense now??

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to setup an XML format file to handle CSV with double quotes:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="0" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="1"/>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="&quot;,&quot;" MAX_LENGTH="12"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="&quot;,&quot;" MAX_LENGTH="38"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="&quot;,&quot;" MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="&quot;,&quot;" MAX_LENGTH="11" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="SequenceID" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="TransactionID" xsi:type="SQLUNIQUEID"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Product_Name" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Product_Code" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

If you want to handle pipe-delimited instead, change `"&quot;,&quot;"` to `"&quot;|&quot;"`